# Group in which one subgroup is contained in every subgroup

Tags: group-theory

let $G$ be a finite abelian group such that it contains a subgroup $H_0\neq \{e\}$ which is contained in every subgroup $H\neq \{e\}$  of $G$

Prove that $G$ is cyclic.Find $o(G)$

How should I start?

**My thoughts:**
Since $G$ is a finite abelian group ,$G$ can be expressed as a direct product of cyclic groups.Let $G=\mathbb Z_{p_1^{\alpha_1}}\times \mathbb Z_{p_2^{\alpha_2}}\times   ...\times\mathbb Z_{p_n^{\alpha_n}}$.

Let $H_0$ be a subgroup of $G$ contained in every other subgroup of $G$ .Now each $\mathbb Z_{p_i^{\alpha_i}}$ can be viewed as a subgroup of $G$ .

So $H_0$ is contained in each $\mathbb Z_{p_i^{\alpha_i}}$ for each $i=1,2,...,n$. So $o(H_0)$ divides $p_i^{\alpha_i}$ for each $i=1,2,...,n$ which is not possible as $p_i$ 's are mutually prime; hence contradiction

So $i=1$ only so $G=\mathbb Z_{p_1^{\alpha_1}}$ which is cyclic.Is this true??Please help.

Comment: For any $g\in G$, its order is divisible by $n$. Not sure how that would help though...

Comment: please dont vote to close

Comment: one observation is that it is certainly not true for nonabelian group for example $G=Q_8$.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Finite abelian group with common nontrivial subgroup $H_0$ is cyclic.](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/520340/finite-abelian-group-with-common-nontrivial-subgroup-h-0-is-cyclic)

Comment: You might want to check this http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/520340/finite-abelian-group-with-common-nontrivial-subgroup-h-0-is-cyclic

Comment: @Arpit Though interestingly, it is close. The only other examples are the generalized quaternion groups.

Comment: I do not think it is a duplicate, as it asks about a specific approach (that is not even treated on dupe-target)

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $K\le G$ is a non-trivial subgroup of $G$ and that for every non-trivial subgroup $X\le G$, we have $K\le X$.
Then $K$ itself has no nontrivial subgroup. Moreover, for any $k\in K\setminus\{1\}$, we have $\langle k\rangle=K$ and thus  $K\cong \mathbb Z/p\mathbb Z$ for some prime$p$

Let $g\in G\setminus\{1\}$ be arbitrary. Then $k\in\langle k\rangle =  K\le \langle g\rangle$, i.e. $k=g^n$ for some $n$. If we write $n=p^mr$ with $r$ not divisible by $p$, then $h:=g^{p^{m+1}}$ has order dividing $r$ (because $h^r=g^{pn}=k^p=1$) and thus $k\notin \langle h\rangle$, from which we conclude $h=1$, hence $g^{p^{m+1}}=1$ and the order of $g$ is a power of $p$.  This shows that $G$ is a $p$-group.Now can you conclude?

Comment: Why dont you say whether mine is correct or not?

Comment: @learnmore  clearly your proof is not valid as explained by others too. Most of the time I avoid nontrivial theorems and the theorem you used is nontrivial result.(atleast to me).

Answer (score 0):

Your proof is not correct.

The main reason it is not correct is that  it is **not true** that the $p_i$ can be taken to be **distinct** in the decomposition you mentioned. 
(Moreover it is cleaner to say $G$ is isomorphic to that group, not that it is equal.)

However, you can use the decomposition you recalled and just say that since you have the subgroups you mention *and* the intersection of two such subgroups is the trivial group there can be only one such group. So, $n=1$ and the group is cyclic. In fact it is even cyclic of prime power order, which is perhaps what is meant by finding the order. (Note that a cyclic group not of prime power order does in fact not have the property you want.)

Comment: The groups will not be the same, not even isomorphic. Note $Z_p \times Z_p$ is not the same as $Z_{p^2}$.  (Indeed, when the primes are distinct you could collect then together in one cyclic group $Z_p \times Z_q$ is isomorphic to $Z_{pq}$ for distinct primes $p$ and $q$; this is basically Chinese Remainder Theorem. But this is not relevant here.)

Comment: I did never say that  $\alpha_i=1$. I said $n=1$ and in the examples I gave there is just no exponent for convenience of the presentation.

Comment: Yes, prime **power** order. The order is a power of a prime.

Comment: sorry i misunderstood that